# Raster calculations python

Tags: python, rasterio

I am using Gtif files for raster calculations in python. I want to apply the formula:

**Aridity index =  precipitation/(Temperature + 10).**

When I use this for Gtiff I get the following error:
*"TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'DatasetReader' and 'DatasetReader".*

I am new to python. Thank you

Here is my code:

```
tmp_tif= rasterio.open('temp.tif')
pcp_tif = rasterio.open('pcp.tif')

AI_DM = pcp_tif/tmp_tif + 10
```

Comment: [Docs say](https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/reading.html) you should `read()` the `DatasetReader` to get the array. Then you can perform operations on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @alex points out (see comments), you should read the contents of the DatasetReaders first (see [Documentation](https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/reading.html))

Therefore, what you want to do is this:

```py
tmp_tif= rasterio.open('temp.tif').read()
pcp_tif = rasterio.open('pcp.tif').read()

AI_DM = pcp_tif/tmp_tif + 10
```